# Graphical Glitch - Outlook 2013 on a 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Server as a Remote App

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, outlook, remote-desktop-services, rds, remoteapp

Server 2008 R2 SP1, with Remote Desktop Services.

Office 2013.

[Edit: Most] Microsoft updates installed.

Publish Outlook as a RemoteApp, and run it from a Windows 8 client, then open an email. What happens is this:

[image: Outlook graphical glitch]

- The email opens and renders briefly, but the Outlook inbox becomes partly-visible through the email.
- Most of the email is invisible, as if it was in the background, except the border remains visible like an embossed imprint.
- The partly-invisible email is actually in the foreground, the visible Outlook main window is in the background.

Moving things around, clicking on them, causing a refresh, fixes the display. Sometimes waiting does. It happens pretty much every email, but not exactly every one.

Disabling hardware acceleration in the Outlook options doesn't make a difference, nor does disabling add-ins, nor does changing the LoadBehaviour in the add-in registry entries.

Using a full remote desktop session, Outlook works fine.

It happens on multiple Windows 8 clients, too. Not sure about Win 7.

Any ideas, please?

[Edit: Disabling themes, menu animations, bitmap cache persistance, font smoothing, etc. in the RDP connection - all make no difference].

[Edit: Also tried:
 - Disabling desktop composition, and menu/window animations on the server
 - Running Outlook in 'safe' mode (with Outlook.exe /safe)
 - Changing Outlook theme
 - Connecting to my PC using RDP, then opening the remote app, to try and get around it being my video drivers.
 - The latest round of Windows/Office updates on the servers.
 - Removing/recreating my RDS User Profile.

All no change.

Tried on 3x Windows 8 PCs, all exhibit this behavior. Tried on 3x Win 7 PCs, only one does this, the other two appear OK.

]

Comment: Do all of the Win8 clients have the same graphics card / driver set? If so, it might be worth testing a differing one. I strongly suspect this to be the client's problem.

Comment: Nope, I have Radeon 4000/5000 series, the other main one has an ATI FireGL, and I've just watched it happen on a Windows 8 / nVidia client and a Win 7 nVidia client.

Comment: Added updates in an edit.

Comment: There is a hotfix for a problem which sound remotely related. Check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981156/en-us and see if it helps matters.

Answer (score 1):

A [post in the Microsoft Partner Support Forum](http://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mpndataplat/forum/mpncatwinsvr-mpnws2008r2/remote-desktop-services-2008-r2-outlook-2013/26448df8-2e9c-44ff-abcc-3284e3d44fa9?tm=1378111599675) did yield these two possible approaches:

1. enable RDP 8.0 via the update [2592687](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592687/en-us)
2. install the [hotfix from KB2786923](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2786923/en-us)

but none seemed to ultimately fix the specific issue, yet they might be worth trying.

Comment: This is probably more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I can't see your post, as I have no login that works. Did you get any answers that helped?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler check out the post's update